# Oracle Expression for Sorting by Number between two Characters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, expression

I have the following values in a `VARCHAR2` column named `ID_PETITION`:

```
Petition_001#1_30
Petition_001#2_30
Petition_001#3_30
...
Petition_001#30_30
```

I want to sort ascending by the number between `#` and `_` characters.

```
SELECT * 
FROM PETITIONS 
WHERE ID_PETITION like 'Petition_001%'
ORDER BY
```

?

Comment: Have you tried anythign yet?

Comment: Does your regexp_substr return the correct number part you want to order by? If yes, you can use that expression in an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: as these are strings, I see an "invalid number" exception in your future (even 1 bad entry will blow up your query when you try using to_number).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from yourtable
order by
to_number(substr(yourcolumn,
          instr(yourcolumn,'#')+1 ,
          instr(yourcolumn,'_',10) - (instr(yourcolumn,'#')+1)))
```

This assumes that the strings will always be in the format "Petition_001#< Numeric value >_3". Since this query gets the text between the first occurence of # and the occurence of _ immediately after it, it is extensible to any number of digits. If you have only single digit values, then you can just use:

```
to_number(substr(yourcolumn), instr(yourcolumn,'#')+1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regexp_substr('Peticion_001#1_3','(#)[[:digit:]]+(_)',1)
```

**Usage in Query:**

```
    select *, to_number(translate(
                 regexp_substr(your_column,'(#)[[:digit:]]+(_)',1),
                 ' #_',
                 ' '
              )) as sortkey
   from your_table
   order by sort_key
```

Better to Write a `Function` to extract the number, and return `null` in case of exceptions. By which we can save *invalid number* exception.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem you'll face is that you'll find that you have 1 or more rows with data that doesn't meet this pattern exactly.  Most likely if you try to convert the chars between # and _ to a number, you hit a few that are NOT numbers, and the entire query will fail with an "invalid number" exception.

You can try using lpad with regexp_substr to avoid using the to_number function:

```
with dat as (
    select 'Petition_001#1_30' as col1 from dual
    union all
    select 'Petition_001#2_30' as col1 from dual
    union all
    select 'Petition_001#XX_30' as col1 from dual
    union all
    select 'Petition_001#10_30' as col1 from dual
    union all
    select 'Petition_001#12_30' as col1 from dual
    union all
    select 'Petition_001#111_30' as col1 from dual
    union all
    select 'Petition_001#999_30' as col1 from dual
)
select col1
    --,regexp_substr(col1, '(#)(([[:digit:]])+)?(_)', 1, 1, 'i', 2) as str_num
    --,lpad(regexp_substr(col1, '(#)(([[:digit:]])+)?(_)', 1, 1, 'i', 2), 4) as str_pad
from dat
order by lpad(regexp_substr(col1, '(#)(([[:digit:]])+)?(_)', 1, 1, 'i', 2), 4);
```

Output:

```
COL1
Petition_001#1_30
Petition_001#2_30
Petition_001#10_30
Petition_001#12_30
Petition_001#111_30
Petition_001#999_30
Petition_001#XX_30
```

Comment: the chars between # and _ are always numbers.